# Getting more than one Image onto the app?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm working on a pizza app and want to add images to go with the checkbutton option, I can get one image on there just fine but when I go to put the next image on it replaces the first, I'm really lost on what to do. This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import webbrowser

URL = "http://pizzahut.com.au"
pizza = tk.Tk()
pizza.title("Pizza App")
pizza.geometry("300x400")

def open_ph(event):
    webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://pizzahut.com.au")

button = tk.Button(pizza, text="Welcome to Awesome Pizza")
button.grid(column=0, row=0)
button.configure(foreground="black")
button.configure(background="red")

checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(pizza, text="Meat Lovers")
checkbutton.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=(5, 95))
checkbutton.configure(foreground="red")

checkbutton2 = tk.Checkbutton(pizza, text="Supreme")
checkbutton2.grid(column=0, row=20, padx=(10, 120))
checkbutton2.configure(foreground="darkgreen")

image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\simon\desktop\pictures\pizza_pics\meat_lovers.jpg")
image.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label_image = tk.Label(image=photo)
label_image.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=(5, 95))

second_image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\simon\Desktop\pictures\pizza_pics\supreme.jpg")
second_image.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(second_image)
label_image = tk.Label(image=photo)
label_image.grid(column=0, row=10)

button.bind("<Button-1>", open_ph)
pizza.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to properly display `ImageTk.PhotoImage` images, you need to keep a **persistent reference** to each of them (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481110/4084269) and the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)).

Therefore, when you define a second `ImageTk.PhotoImage`, you should assign it to a new variable instead of overwriting the first one:

```
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(second_image)
label_image2 = tk.Label(image=photo2)
label_image2.grid(column=0, row=10)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand it better now

Comment: Great! You can click on "accept" if my answer fixed your problem ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer