# Can't call up more than one item from function

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

I am creating a game similar to the atari game; pole position. I am trying to figure out how to get random car to show up each time someone crosses the starting line. I am having trouble calling up more than one random car. I get no error messages. Below is my code. (if you have any suggestions on how to get the cars to show up specifically on the track, that would be helpful as well) I am a beginner at programming and am still trying to figure it out. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
import random
import time
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
            self.tk = Tk()
            self.tk.title("Car Game")
            self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
            self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
            self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=1280, height=750,  bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
            self.canvas.pack()
            self.tk.update()
            self.bg = PhotoImage(file="road.gif")
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.bg, anchor='nw')


    def your_car_sprite(self):
        self.yourCar = PhotoImage(file="carForgame.gif")
        self.canvas.create_image(850,570,image=self.yourCar, anchor='nw')

    def random_cars_sprite(self):
        x = random.randint(0,1280)
        y = random.randint(0,750)
        self.randomCar = PhotoImage(file='Car2.gif')
        self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.randomCar, anchor='nw')
        for i in range(1,5):
            self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.randomCar, anchor='nw')

    def mainloop(self):    
        while 1:
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            self.tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)



g = Game()
g.your_car_sprite()
rCars = g.random_cars_sprite()
main = mainloop()
```

Comment: why did you write your own `mainloop` method? It will be less efficient than just calling the `mainloop` method provided by tkinter.

Comment: Could you explain how to call up my own mainloop function?

Comment: I don't see any code for a starting line, or do I see any code for moving objects.

Comment: I have not gotten that far. I am simply trying to get the cars on the canvas before I go any farther.

Comment: call `self.tk.mainloop()` from within the `Game` class, or `g.tk.mainloop()` outside the class.

Comment: I added it in but now I have an error that pops up saying that there is a runtime error.

Comment: without knowing what the runtime error is, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bonniethiessen/Documents/CarGame/carGameRoadPart.py", line 39, in <module>
    g.your_car_sprite()
  File "/Users/bonniethiessen/Documents/CarGame/carGameRoadPart.py", line 19, in your_car_sprite
    self.yourCar = PhotoImage(file="carForgame.gif")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/

Comment: __init__.py", line 3394, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3335, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
RuntimeError: Too early to create image

Comment: Please don't put code and stack traces in the comment section, it's impossible to read. Add the information by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 reasons why your random cars wouldn't appear:

- First, you define the random position only once, so all the random cars would appear on top of each other.
- Second, when working with `PhotoImage`, a reference to each different image must be kept (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481110/4084269) and [the documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm))

Here is how you could fix it:

```
def random_cars_sprite(self):
    self.randomCars = []
    for i in range(1,5):
        x = random.randint(0,1280)
        y = random.randint(0,750)
        randomCar = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(folder, "purple.png"))
        self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=randomCar, anchor='nw')
        self.randomCars.append(randomCar)
```