# My code doen't work inside a function, python3/tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter-canvas

I'm using python3 and tkinter, the first code works but the second after I put it into a function it no longer shows the image and I want to know why

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("test")

canv = Canvas(root,width=500, height=500)
canv.pack()
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:/Users/tomas/Desktop/carros/carro2.jpg"))
canv.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=image)


root.mainloop()
```

second code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("test")

def main(): 
    canv = Canvas(root,width=500, height=500)
    canv.pack()
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:/Users/tomas/Desktop/carros/carro2.jpg"))
    canv.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=image)

main()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to properly display `ImageTk.PhotoImage` images, you need to keep a **persistent reference** to each of them (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481110/4084269) and the [documentation](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)).

When your code leaves the `main()` function, your `image` object is garbage-collected. One easy way to fix this is to store the image reference in the canvas object, so that it will not be garbage-collected as long as your canvas exists:

```
...
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:/Users/tomas/Desktop/carros/carro2.jpg"))
canv.img = image
...
```